# which method is called when we override the parent Abstract class method which extends another abstract class?

Tags: inheritance, call, abstract-class, callable, overriding

I have callable class which gets called from an spring Application context file

class1:-

```
class mycallable extends Abstractcallable
    {

 @override
      public int method1(){
//return value;
      }


    }

class2:- 

class Abstractcallable extends AbstractTopCallable
    {
      @override
      call(){
//some logic which I want to execute instead of default logic
      }

 @override
      public int method1(){
//return value;
      }

    }

class3:-

class AbstractTopCallable implements callable
    {
      @override
      call(){
//Default Logic
      }

 public static int method1()

    }
```

`

How many ways I try my control is always going to the AbstractTopCallable class,is it because of the static method I am overriding in class1?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems pretty vague with not much to work with, but if I understand your question, this may help:

You should create a **new** instance of the class *mycallable*. If you do not create a new object, it defaults to the static method.

Comment: Hi mche,thanks for you answer.Its working as expected when Im creating an object and explicitly calling the call() method.But the problem this class is part of batch application which will be called through a spring bean.There's not much to debug.